# How to set up event click on full calendar so you get brought to that event's edit page?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

My calendar on my page looks like this:

[image]

When I click one of these events I wish to go to that specific event's edit page. My code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready ->
        $("#msCalendar").fullCalendar({

            header:
                left: "prev today"
                center: "title"
                right: "month,basicWeek next"

            editable: true

            events: "marketingSchedule"

            eventClick: (event) ->
                window.location = "http://localhost:3000/quotes/1/edit"
        })
```

How do I change the number `1` in the url to always fetch the id of the specific event I clicked on?

When I try:

```
eventClick: (event) ->
                window.location = `http://localhost:3000/quotes/${event.id}/edit`
```

the calendar doesn't load on the page anymore.

**UPDATE:**
When I try:

```
eventClick: (event) ->
                    window.location = ('http://localhost:3000/quotes/' + event.id + '/edit')
```

It works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
eventClick: (event) ->
                window.location = `http://localhost:3000/quotes/${event.id}/edit`
```

**UPD:** which is the equivalent to

```
eventClick: (event) -> 
                (window.location = 'http://localhost:3000/quotes/' + event.id + '/edit')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `url` property of each event object, e.g.

```
{
  id: 123,
  title: "Team Meeting",
  start: "2018-07-06 10:00",
  end: "2018-07-06 11:00",
  url: "quotes/123/edit"
}
```

See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object for details of the property. If the `url` property is present, then the browser will automatically navigate to that page when the event is clicked.